# Create geoip field in elasticsearch template

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, logstash

I am using the `geoip` plugin of `logstash` to get geographical information about hosts.

I am using

```
          geoip {
            source => "dst"
          }
```

which seems to work, but creates the following two fields in my `elasticsearch` documents

[image]

How can I concatenate these in a `geoip` entry?

something like a composite json object in the likes of:

```
"geoip"  : {
  "properties" : {
    "latitude" : { "type" : "half_float" },
    "longitude" : { "type" : "half_float" }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the following field in your index template:

```
{
  "properties": {
     ...
     "geoip": {
       "type": "object",
       "properties": {
         "location": {
           "type": "geo_point"
         }
       }
     }
  }
}
```